# Where to install a new module from when the module is deprecated in Python

Tags: python

I'm currently working on some Python code, and when I try to run the code it spits an error message

```
C:\Users\marra\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\six.py:31: 
DeprecationWarning: The module is deprecated in version 0.21 
and will be removed in version 0.23 since we've dropped support for Python 2.7. 
Please rely on the official version of six (https://pypi.org/project/six/).
  "(https://pypi.org/project/six/).", DeprecationWarning)
```

I understand that "deprecated" means that it contains some old version of module that is no longer updated, and what's recommended to do is to replace the old version with an updated version.

But the problem is that I don't know what to do to update it with a newer version.

Will I need to install something via `Anaconda Prompt (Anaconda3)` with a command like `install XXXX`? 
Or will I need to download something on a certain website? I've already visited the website of the URL shown in the error message `(https://pypi.org/project/six/)` and tried downloading the files that were shown when I clicked "download file" button there, but they were some files that I couldn't open after all.

My OS is Windows 10.

Any suggestion to fix this?

Comment: If possible, can you try `pip install --upgrade MyProject` (substituting "MyProject") from a command prompt?

Comment: I've tried running that command and the command displayed a message like ```Installing collected package: MyProject. Successfully installed MyProject-1.0 ```, but when I tried running the same Python code after reopening the jupyter notebook, the result was the same...

Comment: What's your Python version?

Comment: I installed ```Python 3.7 version``` via ```anaconda.com```.

Answer (score 2):

Try `pip install six`.  That should install the "official" version of `six` exactly as the error message suggests. Hopefully `sklearn` should then use that, in preference to the version of `six` that it bundles inside its own `externals` subdirectory.  If `sklearn` fails to behave in the desired way, the next thing to try would be to ensure it is upgraded to the latest version, by saying `pip install --upgrade sklearn`.  (You may wish to do that anyway.)

Comment: I tried ```pip install six``` first, and the command prompt said ```Requirement already satisfied: six```, so I tried the other one ```pip install --upgrade sklearn``` as well. It seemed to have gone successfully and it says ```Installing collected packages: sklearn. Successfully installed sklearn-0.0```, but when I reopened jupyter notebook and retried with the same code, the same error as the one that I pasted in my original question appeared...

Comment: How about upgrading `six` itself?

Comment: If this answer *didnt* solve your problem, maybe you should un-accept it?

Comment: Yeah I un-accepted it. I tried ```pip install --upgrade six```, but got an error message ```ERROR: astroid 2.3.1 requires typed-ast<1.5,>=1.4.0; implementation_name == "cpython" and python_version < "3.8", which is not installed.
ERROR: astroid 2.3.1 has requirement six==1.12, but you'll have six 1.13.0 which is incompatible.``` It also says ```Installing collected packages: six
  Found existing installation: six 1.12.0
    Uninstalling six-1.12.0:
      Successfully uninstalled six-1.12.0
Successfully installed six-1.13.0```, but when I tried to run the code still got the same error

Comment: Since you are using Anaconda environment, install using conda 'conda install -c anaconda six'. Going forward for any installation, search 'conda install xxx' and it will bring up the right link.